# Combining the JSON array from different parent Array in mule dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a JSON like below

```
{
    "packages": [
        {
            "screenings": [
                {
                    "data": {
                        "educationHistory": [
                            {
                                "school": "Test education 4"
                            },
                            {
                                "school": "Test education 4"
                            }
                        ]

                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": {
                        "educationHistory": [
                            {
                                "major": [
                                    "Business Admin."
                                ],
                                "school": "Test education 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "major": [
                                    "Business Admin."
                                ],
                                "school": "Test education 1"
                            }
                        ]

                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In dataweave I have written like this

```
ns0#EmploymentHistory: {(
    payload.packages[0].screenings.data.educationHistory map {
        ns0#Employer: {
            ns0#EmployerName: $.school
        }
    }
)}
```

I'm getting output like this

```
<ns0:EmploymentHistory>
<ns0:Employer>
  <ns0:EmployerName>
    <school>Test education 4</school>
    <school>Test education 4</school>
  </ns0:EmployerName>
</ns0:Employer>
<ns0:Employer>
  <ns0:EmployerName>
    <school>Test education 1</school>
    <school>Test education 1</school>
  </ns0:EmployerName>
</ns0:Employer>
</ns0:EmploymentHistory>
```

I need like below

```
<ns0:EmploymentHistory>
    <ns0:Employer>
      <ns0:EmployerName>
        <school>Test education 4</school>
      </ns0:EmployerName>
    </ns0:Employer>
    <ns0:Employer>
      <ns0:EmployerName>
        <school>Test education 4</school>
      </ns0:EmployerName>
    </ns0:Employer>
    <ns0:Employer>
      <ns0:EmployerName>
        <school>Test education 1</school>
      </ns0:EmployerName>
    </ns0:Employer>
    <ns0:Employer>
      <ns0:EmployerName>
        <school>Test education 1</school>
      </ns0:EmployerName>
    </ns0:Employer>
</ns0:EmploymentHistory>
```

This xpath `payload.packages[0].screenings.data.educationHistory map {` loop through `screening`  not `educationHistory`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the descendants selector, `..`, to get all the `educationHistory` values at one time. This will search down the entire tree from the parent element (in this case `payload.packages[0]`), and grab every matching child element (in this case `educationHistory`). Since `educationHistory` is an array in both instances, this will return an array of arrays, so we need to use `flatten` so we have an array of objects instead:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/xml

%var employers = flatten payload.packages[0]..educationHistory
---
{
  EmploymentHistory: {
    (employers map {
      Employer: {
        EmployerName: {
          School: $.school
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

You can find information about the descendants selector [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-selectors#descendants-selector). Here's the official word from MuleSoft:

> [The descendants selector] is applied to the context using the form `..` and retrieves the values of all matching key:value pairs in the sub-tree under the current context. Regardless of the hierarchical structure these fields are organized in, they are all placed at the same level in the output.